# Is it possible to display .Obj model (with .mtl if possible) to helix3d using an URL? WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, amazon-s3, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

I have an aws s3 bucket containing both .obj and .mtl files of various models.
I wanted to know if it is possible to load to helix3d using each file's URL, as a workaround for downloading each file into the user's machine.